no me da la palabra reservada add member en sql y tengo el sql 2022
ALTER ROLE db_owner ADD MEMBER [usuario1]; GO DENY UPDATE ON Producto TO usuario1  

No me da la palabra reservada member y tengo el sql 2022


A que te refieres que no te da la palabra ? en donde no te la da, podrías mostrar una imagen de eso ? La imagen que agregaste no muestra tu problema.
